# How to test bindings with useNativeEncoding=true in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to test an application with the following binding configured:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        accountSource:
          destination: account
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESSES}
          producer-properties:
            schema.registry.url: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
            value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
        bindings:
          accountSource:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key:
                  serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value:
                  serializer: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer
```

When running the application normally, `AbstractMessageChannel.interceptorList` is empty and sending message to broker works fine.

When running the test (with `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` binder), `AbstractMessageChannel.interceptorList` gets populated with `MessageConverterConfigurer` and message is being converted using content-type serialization mechanisms (Avro object is converted to JSON). This is the test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AccountServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@Autowired
private MessageCollector messageCollector;

@Autowired
private MessageChannel accountSource;

@Test
public void create() {

    // Simplified code
    AccountCreationRequest accountCreationRequest = AccountCreationRequest.builder().company(company).subscription(subscription).user(user).build();

    accountCreationRequest = accountService.create(accountCreationRequest);

    Message<?> message = messageCollector.forChannel(accountSource).poll();
    // execute asserts on message
}

@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class)
static protected class AccountServiceImplTestConfiguration {

@EnableBinding({KafkaConfig.AccountBinding.class})

public interface AccountBinding {
    @Output("accountSource")
    MessageChannel accountSource();
}
}
```

Am I missing something to disable spring-cloud-stream serialization mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the test binder; use the Kafka binder with an embedded kafka broker instead.